# Ububntu 14.04 Периодическое ускорение работы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, время

Здравствуйте.
Обновил Ubuntu c 12.10 до 14.04.
Появилась   следующая проблема:
С периодом в 60 секунд меняется частота мерцания курсора в полях ввода.
При этом, когда курсор быстро мерцает, то при нажатии одного символа - в поле вводится несколько. И так во всех приложениях.
Ещё заметил, что в Хроме в тот момент, когда курсор часто моргает - ускоряется анимация баннеров, и индикатора загрузки страницы.
При запуске пинга частота отправки пакетов также меняется с периодом в 60 секунд от 1 пакета в секунду, до ~10 пакетов в секунду.
Вопрос: было ли у кого-нибудь, что-нибудь подобное?
Если было, то как решили?

Comment: 1. а системное время не «сбивается»? 2. вот такая команда: `while true; do date +'%T'; sleep 1; done`, раз в секунду выводящая текущее время, тоже периодически «ускоряется», или работает без «ускорений»?

Comment: @alexander barakin Спасибо Александр. Время действительно сбивается. 00:32 на часах компьютера, хотя реально 22:52. Буду копать в сторону таймера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашел решение [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3689/clock-running-too-fast)

Нужно добавить в конфиг `grub` для загружаемой системы, опцию: `clock=tsc`