# Спешит время на сервере, как исправить?

Tags: ubuntu, время

Здравствуйте! Такая проблема, на сервере время очень быстро летит вперед, я бы хотел разобраться в причинах этого явления и в способах его устранения.

Не помню во сколько делал сегодня синхронизацию, в районе 13:00 наверное

```
u@devel:~$ sudo ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com
20 Jul 17:45:46 ntpdate[30158]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset -8.288376 sec
```

За 4.5 часа набежало 8.2 секунды

```
u@devel:~$ sudo ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com
[sudo] password for u:
20 Jul 18:12:00 ntpdate[925]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.823899 sec
```

Ну и тут тоже, за полчаса набежала почти секунда...

Как это? Что это? Как с этим бороться? Ставить в крон баш скрипт и каждый час запускать синхронизацию?

Comment: Если сервер аппаратный, скорее всего, кривой/поплывший генератор в RTC, и да, придется синхронизировать NTP довольно часто. Если виртуальный, попробуйте отрубить синхронизацию времени с хостом.

Comment: вообще, конечно, надо ставить `ntpd`. ещё на [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420560/178576) посмотрите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если нет периодических больших ускорений/замедлений, которые упомянуты, например, в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420560/178576), то для синхранизации времени сто́ит установить `ntpd`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntpd
```

если время в системе слишком сильно расходится с «эталонным» (больше нескольких секунд), то перед установкой (точнее, перед запуском) `ntpd` необходимо установить время клиентом `ntpdate`:

```
$ sudo ntpdate ru.pool.ntp.org
```

---

вообще, этот демон я бы рекомендовал устанавливать **всегда** и на **все** системы (кроме, разве, чего-то узко-специализированного).