# Время на сервере спешит

Tags: синхронизация, opensuse, ntp

Есть сервер удаленный сервер на хостинге у провайдера. Сервер представляет собой виртуальную машину, поднятую на Virtulbox'е. На нем установлена openSUSE 42.1. Проблема в следующем: за сутки работы сервер рассинхронизируется по времени примерно на 12 минут. Что можно c этим сделать?
P.S. Советы, изложенные по ссылке ниже не помогли.
[Спешит время на сервере, как исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436915/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Запустите сервер ntpd (не забыв поставить у него в конфиге несколько серверов с которыми он будет синхронизироваться). ntpd идет в том же пакете, что и ntpdate

Comment: Пробовал. Проблема остаётся

Comment: Хм. это странно. сколько разных серверов вы указывали в конфиге как `server` и следили ли вы за тем как оно работает с помощью команды `peers` в утилите `ntpq`